# How to count the number of elements in an array below/above a given number (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, counting

It's example of array which contains only numbers:

`var array = [3.1, 1, 2.2, 5.1, 6, 7.3, 2.1, 9]`

### EDITED

How to count **how many(edited from word 'sum')** of elements are in array below / above given number eg. '5.25'?

So answer should be `5` elements are below (3.1, 1, 2.2, 5.1, 2.1) and `3` element are above (6, 7.3, 9)

Comment: why not use third party like lodash....will make things easy

Comment: @RohitasBehera "Easy" is not the goal, learning is.

Comment: @RohitasBehera 1. I can't use lodash in that case 2. It's question about pure js

Comment: agreed...my answer is just good to know ...might be be useful in some oder scenario

Comment: You changed the total question.

Comment: @Durga Yes, I edited it and added comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an object `{ above: 0, below: 0 }` as initial value. On each iteration check each number against the media, and accordingly add 1 to above/below.

Note: This is an array of strings. I've converted them manually to numbers. I also assume that a number that equals the median should be added to below. If you want to skip this numbers, change the comparison to `<`.

```js
var array = [3.1, 1, 2.2, 5.1, 6, 7.3, 2.1, 9];

var median = 5.25;

var counts = array.reduce(function(s, n) {
  s[n <= median ? 'below' : 'above'] += 1;
  
  return s;
}, { above: 0, below: 0 });

console.log(counts);
```

If you must have an array of strings, you can convert to a number in run time using [String#parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) or the [`+` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus):

```js
var array = ['3.1', '1', '2.2', '5.1', '6', '7.3', '2.1', '9'];

var median = 5.25;

var counts = array.reduce(function(s, str) {
  s[+str <= median ? 'below' : 'above'] += 1;
  
  return s;
}, { above: 0, below: 0 });

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: how you converted a string array to number array ??

Comment: @RohitasBehera strings was no main case here

Comment: @OriDrori thanks for answer but... sorry I asked question in not correct way :| I edited question

Comment: @CodeJoe - the answer was already updated to fit the question. Try again.

Comment: @OriDrori great! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

No need for reduce, because the result does not change by using reduce, it is still an object.

```js
var array = [3.1, 1, 2.2, 5.1, 6, 7.3, 2.1, 9],
    value = 5.25,
    counts = { below: 0, equal: 0, above: 0 };

array.forEach(function(v) {
    counts[{ '-1': 'below', 0: 'equal', 1: 'above' }[Math.sign(v - value)]]++;
});

console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an array of numbers..

I use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) ...it helps shorten the code &

```js
var array = [3.1, 1, 2.2, 5.1, 6, 7.3, 2.1, 9];


console.log(_.sum(array));   //  _.sum  does the addition
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of strategies but I will use the one thats easy to read and understand:

(1) Create a new array with all elements that fit the criteria aka <=5.25

```
let sampleArr = ['3.1', '1', '2.2', '5.1', '6', '7.3', '2.1', '9'];

let sortedArr = sampleArr.filter(function(e){
     return parseInt(e) <= 5.25
});
```

Notice I wrote parseInt(e), that converts the string into a number. The values you gave in your array were all strings.

(2) Now simply get the length of the sortedArr like so:

```
let finalCount = sortedArr.length;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I asked question in wrong way (it's edited now). I mean "how many of elements are below/above given number". But you answer helped me :) I just need to use `.filter` and count length of  `sortedArr`. Thanks

Comment: Always happy to help! Could you please select my response as the answer to the question. Thanks :)